# How can my Android app use the system's background image as its image?

Tags: android

I'm not sure about older versions of Android, but in Android 2.1 and 2.2, the system clock application doesn't have its own background. Instead, it uses the system's background. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is using a transparent image

Comment: I've never had a reason to go back and try this, but I think you may be right. I know there are also different themes that can be applied to apps.